# How to authenticate User from mysql in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to implement login app. all the users information are in table named 'admin_users'. I am using mysql server by xampp.

when i am authenticating using `user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)`
On printing user I am getting `None`.

I am beginner in django and I could not find out whats wrong.
If I am doing `AdminUsers.objects.all()` I can print all the table information.

models.py

```
class AdminUsers(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mail=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    class Meta:
        db_table="admin_users"
```

view.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        print(user)
    return render(request,'AdminUsers/login.html')
```

my index.html contains simple forms with username and password.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for python_test project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-j*uh&s1$j-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'python_test.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'app_kanri/templates/app_kanri/')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'python_test.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert this in your settings: `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'AppName.AdminUsers'` (replace AppName with the name of the app containing AdminUsers).

Your custom User model should inherit from AbstractUser to be compatible with the authentication system (right now it will not work):

```
class AdminUsers(AbstractUser):
    department=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table='admin_users'
```

Now AdminUsers will inherit fields of AbstractUser (username, email, password, is_staff, ...), read this for [details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/).
If you have already done migrations, you need to delete migrations of the default User model.

Note also that you should name the model 'AdminUser' and not 'AdminUsers'.

Comment: I used same model but ``` user=AdminUser.objects.get(username=username) ``` and I can match the password by user.password. Is this method okay?

Comment: @anonymous, no Django store the hashed password in the database and not the raw data, now you are comparing the plain password with its hash. You need to use: `user.check_password(password)` that compares hashes for you

Comment: To match the password, I used bcrypt.checkpw() and I was storing the password using bcrypt.hashpw(). This solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your goal is with the AdminUsers model. The default django user model has flags like is_staff and is_superuser that you can use to seperate users and their permissions with regards to what they can access on the app.
Check out the docs on the user model [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/)